# Generating random Triangles in Applet (Animation)

Tags: java, applet

I try to solve this question, but I have an infinite loop and don't know how to solve this problem. Guide me. I'm new in Java.

In terminal:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at ThreadApplet.RandGen(ThreadApplet.java:10)
        at ThreadApplet.paint(ThreadApplet.java:30)
        at java.awt.Container.update(Container.java:1988)
        at sun.awt.RepaintArea.updateComponent(RepaintArea.java:255)
```

Thanks for HELP!

Question: Write an applet that displays randomly generated triangles in different colors.

```
    /////////////Applet

import java.awt.*;

import java.applet.*;

public class ThreadApplet extends Applet{
    MyThread thread;
    int x[],y[];
    public boolean ctrl=true;

    public void RandGen(){
        for (int i=0; i<3;i++){
            x[i]=(int)Math.random()*100;
            y[i]=(int)Math.random()*100;
        }       
    }

    public void start(){
        if (thread==null){
            thread = new MyThread(this);
            thread.start();
        }
    }

    public void stop(){
        thread = null;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        if (ctrl==true){
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.red);
        }
        RandGen();
        g.fillPolygon(x,y,3);   
    }
}

public class MyThread extends Thread{
    ThreadApplet applet;

    public MyThread (ThreadApplet applet){
        this.applet=applet;
    }
    public void run(){
        Thread thisThread = Thread.currentThread();
        while (this==thisThread){           
            applet.repaint();
            try{Thread.sleep(50);}
            catch(InterruptedException e){} 
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: If you ever run into a NullPointerException again, check out the line that throws it as this will usually tell which variable is null that shouldn't be null. If you still can't solve it and need our help, then please tell ***us*** the line that causes it (give it an obvious **big** comment), so we won't have to struggle to guess which line it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize your arrays before usage:

```
 int x[] = new int[17];
```

for example.